# WebBrowser in C# console application won't navigate

Tags: c#, console, webbrowser-control

I can't get the `WebBrowser` class to open a website.

Here's my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    // This is pseudo code
    class Program
    {
        private static String mail = "example@mail.com";
        private static String password = "randomPassword";

        private static String url = "http://www.loginUrl.com";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser.Navigate(url);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        void AutoLogin()
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait(mail);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait(password);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        }
    }
```

I read through multiple forums, where users had the same problem but I can't seem to fix it. It just doesn't make any sense. Please don't try to give me other
 methods than using webbrowser. I want to be able to know when the desired page
 finished loading that's why I'm using webbrowser and not Process.Start() or 
something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It navigates correctly, you navigate in a browser control which you never show.

Comment: You should host `WebBrowser` control inside window, not from console

Answer (score 0):

You can open browser with the following command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

In the sample you provided you create WebBrowser control, navigate in it and dispose it. Maybe you need `WinForms` App instead of `Console` app and put your WebBrowser on the form.